# Create counter variable

Tags: variables, counter, stata

I am using Stata 13.

I want to create a variable that equals 0 when none of a bunch of other variables equals 0; this variable is 1 when one variable of a bunch of other variables equals 1; it is 2 when two variables of a bunch of other variables are 1; it is 3 when three variables of a bunch of other variables are 1; and so on.

Any suggestions?

Comment: As a possible solution I have just found the following: egen total = rowtotal(v1 v2 v3 v4). It is funny that I have thought about this solution only now, after I have posted my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your conditions are not mutually exclusive. Two criteria need to be separated.

1. A variable that is 0 when none of a bunch of other variables equals 0.
2. A variable is 1 when one variable of a bunch of other variables equals 1; 2 when two variables are 1; 3 when three variables are 1; etc.

Condition #2 is just counting 1s, as here:

```
clear 
input x1 x2 x3 
0 0 1 
0 1 1 
1 1 1 
end 

egen count1 = anycount(x1 x2 x3), value(1) 

list 

     +-----------------------+
     | x1   x2   x3   count1 |
     |-----------------------|
  1. |  0    0    1        1 |
  2. |  0    1    1        2 |
  3. |  1    1    1        3 |
     +-----------------------+
```

Condition #1 could be done this way for a modest number of variables:

```
gen none0 = inlist(0, x1, x2, x3)

list 

     +-------------------------------+
     | x1   x2   x3   count1   none0 |
     |-------------------------------|
  1. |  0    0    1        1       1 |
  2. |  0    1    1        2       1 |
  3. |  1    1    1        3       0 |
     +-------------------------------+
```

The `rowtotal()` method of counting 1s in your comment only works for values that are only ever 1, 0 or missing, which may be true of your data but it is not a stated condition.

Comment: Thank you @nick! I will take a look into condition #1, that admittedly I had not considered before.